# insert image into mssql using php

Tags: php, html, sql-server, image, blob

I want to insert image into mssql providing option for user to select the image and insert into database.so i used the following code

```
<html>
<head>
<?php 
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
mmysql_connect("localhost","sample","welcome");
mysql_select_db("samples");

if (empty($_POST["frm"]))   
{

}
else
{
$filename=trim($_REQUEST['slcfile']);
$datastring = file_get_contents($filename);
$data         = unpack("H*hex", $datastring);
echo trim($_REQUEST['slcfile']);
mssql_query("insert into imageinserter values ( 0x".$data['hex'].",'.$filename.')"); 
}

}
?>
</head>
<body>
<form name="frm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" >
select image :<input type="file" name="slcfile" /> <br>
<input type="submit" name="slcfile" value="addimage"/> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

but it is saying error error at file_get_contents saying no such file or resource found.
Please help to solve the issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `multipart/form-data` in your form like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
```

and then read the uploaded file by its temp name 
eg: `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name']`

Comment: were do i need to add multipart/form-data?

Comment: i am new to php and html.so please tell me for what attribute do i need to give value in form.

Comment: add enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag

Comment: sorry @krishnakumar as said by  Use that enctype

Comment: can you please tell me what is the parameter to be passed in place of **uploadedfile** .

Comment: can you echo your query and run this in the phpmyadmin or any mysql tool

Comment: use 'slcfile' as your input field nams is "slcfile"

Comment: but it is saying **Undefined index: slcfile** what could be the problem

Comment: Use as $_FILES['srcfiile']['NAME'], Updated the comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26935/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-choudhary-and-krishna-kumar)

Answer (score 0):

You need to allow

```
   allow_url_fopen
```

in your php.ini config file. Some hosts disallow it for security